# Eager Loading with Entity Framework, LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, eager-loading

I am working on ASP.NET MVC project. i am using EF code-first approach. i have 3 classes, which are:

```
public class A
{
    public int AID {get;set;}
    public string A1 {get;set}
    public string A2 {get;set}

    public virtual List<B> Bs {get;set;}
}

public class B
{
    public int BID {get;set;}
    public string B1 {get;set}
    public string B2 {get;set}

    public AID {get;set}
    public virtual A A {get;set}

    public virtual List<C> Cs {get;set;}
}

public class C
{
    public int CID {get;set;}
    public string C1 {get;set}
    public string C2 {get;set}

    public BID {get;set}
    public virtual B B {get;set}
}
```

I want to select only C1 properties of class C based on Class B  where A1 = 4 .
i tried using:

```
var result = db.C.select(x=>x.C1).Include(x=>B).where(x=>x.A.equals(4))
```

I am confused and don't know how to execute the linq query. Also i am not sure whether to continue using eager loading or fall back on something else.

Please can any guru help me out please?

Comment: Do you want to select all properties of all `C` classes that belongs to all `B` classes that below to `A` class which has `A1 = 4` ?

Comment: I dont know what ur doing with an int 4 so i just put tostring on it .....      Await Db.a.where(x=>x.A1.Equals(4.ToString())).select(x=>x.bs.select(y=>y.cs.selectmany(z=>z.c1))).tolistasync()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var result = db.C
    .Where(c => c.B.A.A1 == 4)
    .Select(c => c.C1)
    .ToList()
```

You don't have to use Eager loading (`Include`) here because none of nested entities are contained in the result.

Eager loading is used to workaround SELECT N + 1 problem. This problem arises when you retrieve parent entity and want to iterate through its children. This results in N + 1 requests made to the database.

Here are code samples to illustrate:

**Without Eager Loading**

```
var carList = db.Cars.ToList(); //this will create one request to the database to retrieve all cars

foreach(var car in carList)
{
    foreach(var wheel in car.Wheels) //this line will create another request to the database to retrieve wheels for specific car
    }
        Console.Write("Car = {0}, Wheel = {1}", car, wheel);
    }
}
//Total requests: 1 to get car list + N requests to retrieve wheels where N - total number of cars
```

**With Eager Loading**

```
var carList = db.Cars.Include(x => x.Wheels).ToList(); //this will create one request to the database to retrieve all cars together with information about wheels

foreach(var car in carList)
{
    foreach(var wheel in car.Wheels) //this line won't create extra request to the database because this data has been already loaded using eager loading
    }
        Console.Write("Car = {0}, Wheel = {1}", car, wheel);
    }
}
//Total requests: 1 to get car list with all wheel information
```

Comment: I would include, that to execute a LINQ to Entities Expression, you have to enumerate the collection, i.e. using `ToList`, `Count` etc...

Comment: I am very grateful Kaspars Ozols. Your answer is the best i've heard so far. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

By default EF uses lazy loading, meaning you won't get, until you ask for it. Use ToList() or ToArray() to make EF perform query to sql and put these objects to in- memory entities. 
If you need, you may perform raw sql query like `YourDbContext.SqlQuery<T>("select * from ...")`